# Get value and text of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get an array of selected checkboxes values and text on button click

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" /><label>text1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" /><label>text2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" /><label>text3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4" /><label>text4</label>
```

I'm getting values of the checkboxes but how to get text also in array

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
var vals = 0;
for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        vals += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create an array of the values you require:

```
var labelValues = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return [ $(this).next('label').text(), this.value ];
}).get();
```

However given your desired output it would make more sense to create an object with the labels as the properties, something like this:

```
var obj = {};
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    obj[$(this).next('label').text()] = this.value;
});
```

---

***-- 2021 Update --***

You can now simplify the `map()` call using an ES6 arrow function. In addition you could combine the checkbox value and label text in to an array of objects, like this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', () => {
  let labelValues = $(':checkbox:checked').map((i, el) => ({
    value: el.value,
    text: el.nextElementSibling.textContent
  })).get();

  console.log(labelValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" /><label>text1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" /><label>text2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" /><label>text3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4" /><label>text4</label>
```

Comment: Using the map() approach. Worked like a charm :) Thaknk you so much for your help.. can you seprate value and text array in two variable

Answer (score 2):

@Rory's answers is good to return both value and text into a single array. But as the **OP** is asking to return value and text into separate arrays, I would propose the following way to do that.

All you have to do is to use 2 arrays to get separate values from text.

[**Working JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/L0edn25w/7/)

Run the below snippet to see the output in the console. 
This example will return:

1. Selected checkbox Values in an array
2. Selected checkbox texts in an array
3. Selected checkbox in an array (In case if you want it)

```js
var selectedCheckBoxValue = [];
var selectedCheckBoxText = [];

var selectedCheckBox = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(i) {

  selectedCheckBoxValue[i] = this.value;
  selectedCheckBoxText[i] = $(this).next('label').text();
  return this;
}).get();


//Selected Checkboxes Value in a seperate Array
console.log(selectedCheckBoxValue);

//Selected Checkboxes Text in a seperate Array
console.log(selectedCheckBoxText);

//Selected Checkboxes element in a seperate Array
console.log(selectedCheckBox);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" checked="true" />
<label>text1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" checked="true" />
<label>text2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" />
<label>text3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4" checked="true" />
<label>text4</label>
```